# Laravel controller middleware filter multiple steps?

Tags: laravel-5.1, laravel-middleware

After the user has created an account he's redirected in the following order

1. Register Company
2. Upload logo
3. Upload cover
4. Connect to Stripe
5. General Settings
6. Vouchers Settings
7. Pay Subscription

I have a OwnerController.php that is extends by all controllers related to a company. In it I applied two middlewares
 1. hasAccess - to check if user is loggedin
 2. registrationComplete - to check if all the 7 steps from above have been completed. That way I know the user is ready to use the app and their profile is live.

Here is how I apply the `registrationComplete` middleware

```
$this->middleware('registrationComplete', ['except' => [
'registerView', 'registerPost', 
..... 
'editView' - the view method to update general settings from GeneralSettingsController
'editPost' - same as above except is the post method for same controller
]]);
```

The problem is that in other controllers across the app I have other methods named just the same and if a user changes the url in the address bar they can access restricted areas before they finish the registration process.

I know I can apply it on each route or grouped routes but I have hundreds of routes and that's not an option.

What I want to do is add the controller name as well in the except method of the middleware. Ex

```
$this->middleware('registrationComplete', ['except' => 
'Modules\Settings\Controllers\GeneralSettings@editView',
'Modules\Settings\Controllers\GeneralSettings@editPost'
.....
```

Any idea how I can achieve that?

Thank you